# Displaying the menu button on android 4

Tags: android

I am looking for a way to programmatically display the legacy menu button in android 4.0+ devices.
my app has a full screen activity (without an action bar), and due to different reasons i'd like the user to be able to access some types of functionality without adding a menu button to the UI.

My app uses a lot of the SDK 14+ facilities, so setting it to a legacy api level is not an option.

Thanks!

Comment: Why isn't setting the target API to a lower API level not an option? You won't necessarily lose those newer SDK level functions. Can you provide some details about what you're afraid of losing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to do this without changing it to a legacy API level in the Manifest, sorry.